# Expected end of string, got 'LIMIT' when using LIMIT in DQL Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, dql

I need to get the last Id from my table so i can use it in another function i created this function on my repository but i didn't work it show me an error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 60: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'LIMIT'

the function i'am using :

```
         public function LastIdCart()
          {
            $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("select i.id from BoutiqueBundle:Panier i ORDER BY 
            i.id DESC LIMIT 1");
            return $query->getResult();
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourController extends Controller {

     *********************************************************
     public function yourAction( *** ) {
          $youLastRecord = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(YourEntity::class)->findOneBy(
               array(),
               array('id' => 'DESC')
          );
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your upvote, and I am always #READYTOHELP!

Comment: Do u have an email so i can contact u because i have a little issue and i want to take ur opinion about it if possible of course

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use `OFFSET` and/or `LIMIT` with a `DQL Query` is using the following api on the `$query` object as follow:

```
Query::setMaxResults($maxResults)
Query::setFirstResult($offset)
```

As describe in the doc [First and Max Result Items (DQL Query Only)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only)

As example, your code should be like:

```
     public function LastIdCart()
      {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("select i.id from BoutiqueBundle:Panier i ORDER BY 
        i.id");
         $query->setMaxResults(1);
        return $query->getResult(); // will return an arraycollection with only one element
       }
```

Hope this clarify